# "Can't update in WordPress"

Tags: pages, uploads, updates

WordPress changes can't showing.

WordPress version: 5.5.3

Node version: 14.19.3

PHP version: PHP 7.4.29

npm version: 6.14.17

There is a website under development in WordPress.

I edited the page in page editing window and click  the "Update" button but I can't update it.

I tried this:

- deactivated all plugins
- tried to change the theme
- cleared browser cache

but still can't do it.

Update button is active state always.

After editing the page, click the "Update" button and you will see a notice saying "Please add at least 1 contributor." Click "OK".

After that, the "Update" button is still active.

However, the contents of sql in the database are not changed, and even if you click "Preview Changes", you cannot see the changed contents.

If you exit the page editing window and go back to the editing window, the contents of the page are in the state before editing, and a comment saying "The backup copy of this article is different from the version below in the browser" is displayed.

Now when I click the "Restore the backup" button, return to the state before the update.

I've searched the internet and tried various things, but still can't solve the problem.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try adding at least 1 contributor...?

Comment: Yes, I tried update changed contributor. But can't update.